# ¿Como puedo hacer un patrón Staircase con numeros en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola que tal a todos estoy intentando hacer uso del patron staircase pero utilizando numeros.
En el cual estoy utilizando angular pero no estoy dando con la solucion.
esto es lo que estaria tratando de conseguir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo que hecho hasta el momento:

main.ts :

```
       import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

       @Component({
       selector: "main-component",
       styleUrls: ["./main.component.scss"],
       templateUrl: "./main.component.html"
       })

      export class MainComponent {
      @Input()
      elements: number = 1;
      max = 100;
      x = new Array();

      ngOnInit() {
       this.updateValue();
      }

      updateValue() {

      this.x = new Array();
       for (let i = 1; i <= this.elements; i++) {
        this.x.push(i);
        }
       }
      }
```

main.html:

```
<input
 type="number"
 min="1"
 max="100"
 (change)="updateValue()"
 [(ngModel)]="elements"
 />

<div>
 <span class="number" *ngFor="let row of x">
  {{row}}
 </span>

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of x">
    <td *ngFor="let td of row"> {{row}} </td> 
  <!-- TODO -->
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar para lo que necesita.

Typescript

```
elements: number = 32;
max = 100;
x: any[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateValue();
}
updateValue() {
    this.x = [];
    let idx = 1;
    let last = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.elements; i++) {
        const inner: number[] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < idx; j++) {
            if (last > this.elements) break;
            inner.push(last);
            last++;
        }
        this.x.push(inner);
        idx++;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<p>Number input:</p>
<input
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="100"
    (change)="updateValue()"
    [(ngModel)]="elements"
/>
<div>
<p>Staircase: </p>
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of x">
      <td *ngFor="let td of row"
        style="padding: 10px; background-color: gray; text-align: center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bolder;">
        {{td}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JavierSiacca Te funciono ?

Comment: Si, funciona perfecto!